# (ValueError) How to set data shape in RNN?

Tags: python, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I have a problem with data shape in RNN model.

```
y_pred = model.predict(X_test_re) # X_test_re.shape (35,1,1)
```

It returned an error like below.
**ValueError: In a stateful network, you should only pass inputs with a number of samples that can be divided by the batch size. Found: 35 samples. Batch size: 32.**

1. first Question
   I can't understand because I defined batch_size=10, but why error msg says batch size:32?
2. Second Question
   when I modified the code as below

```
model.predict(X_test_re[:32])
```

I also got an error msg but I don't know what it means.
**InvalidArgumentError: Incompatible shapes: [32,20] vs. [10,20]
     [[{{node lstm_1/while/add_1}}]]**

I built a model and fit it as below.

```
features = 1
timesteps = 1
batch_size = 10

K.clear_session()
model=Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(20, return_sequences=True, stateful=True,
               batch_input_shape=(batch_size, timesteps, features)))
model.add(LSTM(20, stateful=True))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
model.summary()
```

[image]

```
earyl_stop = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=5, verbose=1)
hist = model.fit(X_train_re, y_train, # X_train_re.shape (70,1,1), y_train(70,)
                 batch_size=batch_size,
                 epochs=100,
                 verbose=1,
                 shuffle=False,
                 callbacks=[earyl_stop])
```

Until fit model, it works without any problem.

+) source code
first, df looks like,
[image]

```
# split_train_test from dataframe
train,test = df[:-35],df[-35:]
# print(train.shape, test.shape) (70, 2) (35, 2)

# scaling
sc = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(-1,1))
train_sc = sc.fit_transform(train)
test_sc = sc.transform(test)

# Split X,y (column t-1 is X)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_sc[:,1], test_sc[:,1], train_sc[:,0], test_sc[:,0]

# reshape X_train
X_train_re = X_train.reshape(X_train.shape[0],1,1)
X_test_re = X_test.reshape(X_test.shape[0],1,1)
```

Comment: Where is the code for X_train_re, y_train?

Comment: I added the shape of X_train_re, y_train. and sample of X_train_re. This is what you ask?

Comment: No, I am asking for code where you read values into X_train_re, y_train.

Comment: edited with source code where I get X_train_re, y_train